# UPDATE with table a and table b

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
TABLEA ( id - gcoins )
TABLEB ( id - prezzo )
```

Should I do a kind of subtraction: at number/value of 'gcoins' subtract number/value of 'prezzo'.

**I tried:**

```
UPDATE TABLEA SET TABLEA.gcoins = TABLEA.gcoins - TABLEB.prezzo FROM TABLEA JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.id = TABLEB.id;
```

I read this same code in this site at question in the 2010 but not work.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM TABLEA JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.id = TABLEB.id' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rewrite.

```
UPDATE  TABLEA JOIN TABLEB
            ON TABLEA.id = TABLEB.id
SET     TABLEA.gcoins = TABLEA.gcoins - TABLEB.prezzo
```

Comment: I don't undestand your code when you use TableA or TableB. Because if I understand TA is the name of table, it's correct? The different about @TableA and TA ?

Comment: what is the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tablea AS tablea JOIN tableb AS tableb ON tablea.id =' at line 1

Code: UPDATE tablea SET gcoins = tablea.gcoins - tableb.prezzo FROM tablea AS tablea JOIN tableb AS tableb ON tablea.id = tableb.id;

Comment: So i have a question. When I click and "buy" the row 1 it's ok, but if I buy the 2 row it's incorrect because the row "prezzo" is different between 1 and 2 id but out the same "prezzo". Same thing if I buy (I'm a id = 1) it's ok but if but the mybb_users.2 it's error because don't remove "gcoins". I think of add a variable for "id" and "uid" but out and erro of syntax. How can i add the variable and If i can add the variable or code it's incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "UPDATE TABLEA.gcoins", and you don't need wrote again "FROM TABLEA.gcoins". Join goes after the UPDATE value, see this example above:

Try write:
UPDATE (your table) JOIN (your join) ON (your join comparison) SET (your update) WHERE (your clausure if you want)

Comment: I don't understand part of your code: 
UPDATE TABLEA JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.gcoins =TABLEA.gcoins - TABLEB.prezzo SET ? WHERE TABLEA.id = TABLEB.id;

Comment: I don't understand the code for "ON" and "SET" and if the other code it's correct for you